# Java, ByteBuffer get byte[] through array(), then convert byte[] to file. The file is different from the origin one

Tags: java, bytebuffer

Method 1

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = reqData.getByteBuffer();
File localFile = new File(ROOTPATH, localFileName);
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteBuffer.array()), localFile);
```

The file generated is different from the origin one in Method 1.

Method 2

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = reqData.getByteBuffer();
byte[] arr = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
...
```

The file generated is the same as the origin one in Method 2.

Why the bytes got by ByteBuffer.array() is wrong? Is it because of ByteBuffer.array() itself, or ByteArrayInputStream constructor?

Comment: What is the “origin one”? Where does `reqData` come from? Please, show a [mcve].

Comment: `ByteBuffer.array()` returns the whole backing array and you are responsible for taking `position` and `limit` into account. With your second method (probably by using `ByteBuffer.get(byte[])` the `ByteBuffer` takes care of these.

Comment: the issue is probably in the .remaining() method being used, but I can't be sure exactly without you showing what goes wrong and which part of the code, in **it's entirety**, you think is causing the problem

Comment: I think at @0x150 is right. `remaining()` does not guarantee to return the total number of bytes in a file, only the number of bytes that can be read without blocking.

Answer (score -4):

Ah, the mysterious case of the mischievous bytes! Well, my friend, let's unravel this puzzle !

In Method 1, you used ByteBuffer's `array()` method to get the byte array and then converted it into a file using `ByteArrayInputStream`. But alas! The resulting file turned out different from the original.

Now, let's dive into the possible culprits. Could it be ByteBuffer.array() playing tricks on you? Is it secretly swapping bytes like a mischievous imp? Or perhaps, it's the ByteArrayInputStream constructor pulling a prank of its own?

Well, fear not, dear user! The answer lies in how ByteBuffer works. You see, the byte array obtained from `array()` includes the entire internal buffer, not just the portion you've actually written to. It's like taking a snapshot of the whole aquarium, even if you only have a goldfish swimming around.

So when you pass that byte array to `ByteArrayInputStream` and create a new file, you inadvertently include all those extra, unwritten bytes. And voila! You end up with a different file compared to the original. Sneaky, right?

But don't lose hope! Method 2 comes to the rescue. By using `byteBuffer.remaining()` and creating a new byte array with just the necessary length, you avoid capturing those pesky unmodified bytes. Thus, the file generated is identical to the original. Hooray for Method 2!

So the bytes aren't playing games; it's just a quirk of the `array()` method and its sneaky surprises. Keep Method 2 in your pocket, and your files shall remain unaltered. Happy coding my friend, and may your bytes always be well-behaved!

Comment: Generative AI isn't allowed, and MEE6 doesn't provide good answers on top of using AI